# ie8 makes header disappear

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

My website gets completely messed up in < ie8. Specifically my header just disappears, any ideas?

```
    header{
        width: 100%;
        height: 140px;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        margin: 0px;
        float: left;
    }

    h1{
    color: #FFFFFF;
      font-family: Garamond,Baskerville,"Baskerville Old Face","Hoefler                Text","Times New Roman",serif
    }


    .headerInner{
        width: 96%;
        height: 88%;
        background: #00AA4F;
        margin: 10px 2%;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: http://scrapspost.com/batFin/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE8 and older versions don't support HTML5, so it doesn't know about the existence of a header element, therefore it doesn't render it. You can use a div instead of the header element or you can add this script here, which adds HTML5 support for IE8: https://github.com/afarkas/html5shiv. But for IE7 and older I don't think it will help you. I you need to support IE7 and older don't use HTML5 elements.

Comment: Doi of course, currently slapping my head. It is my first full HTML5 site and got caught out. Thank you my friend